# Tilted arrows in latex

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

Here is the figure I want to draw:
[image]

Could someone show me how to draw tilted arrows please? I know how to draw a commutative triangle like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
 \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow [r, dashed ,"\tilde{f}"] \arrow[swap]{dr}{f} & E \arrow{d}{i} \\
     & X
  \end{tikzcd}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `tilted` arrows?

Comment: The arrows are tilted in the picture I gave, they are not either horizontal or vertical @Bernard

Comment: I see. Personally, I use the qualifier ‘*oblique*’ arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tikz-cd` use `dl` to indicate the arrow should go "down-left". Similarly, `dr` is "down-right". Remember to add an extra empty cell in row two below the `A` (which is why there is an `&` before the first cell and two `&&` in the second row). The extra single quote is shorthand for `swap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
  & A \arrow[dl,"f_1"']\arrow[dr,"f_2"] \\
  X && Y
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you want the columns closer together, you can use `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]`, or you can set `column sep=.5cm` or any dimension you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it using **chemfig** and **tikz** packages

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 4mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
X \arrow{<-[$f_1$]}[45,1.5] A \arrow{->[$f_2$]}[315,1.5] Y
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]